# Jobs for gaining experience in preperation for data science

Tags: beginner, career

Data Scientist positions are not the most common entry level jobs. They require hard work, knowledge and most of all experience. The problem is, I am uncertain what entry level jobs can help you get experience in data science. I apologise for not asking a technical question, but I have been searching an answer and most importantly advice from experts and data science practitioners.

Currently, I am studying to become a Data Scientist and I was wondering what are good entry level jobs that can help me build a good foundation for future success in the field?